# python how to make dynamic object name

Tags: python, class, variables, object

i have a class "karte"
i want to know is there a way of dynamic name creation of my new objects normal object creation would be

> karta=karte()

but i am curious in something like this

> karta[i]=karte()

or something like that where i would be the number of for loop. and at the end i would call object like this

```
karta1.boja
karta2.boja
karta3.boja
```

how can i achieve that , im new to python thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can create a list of objects like this:

```
karta = []
for i in range(10):
    karta.append(karte())
```

Or using a list comprehension:

```
karta = [karte() for i in range(10)]
```

Now you can access the objects like this: `karta[i]`.

To accomplish your last example, you have to modify the `globals()` dictionary. I do not endorse this at all, but here is how to do it:

```
g = globals()
for i in range(10):
    g["karte" + str(i)] = karte()
```

This is not very pythonic though, you should just use a list.

Answer (score 6):

Unless you have a real need to keep the objects out of a list and have names like karta1, karta2, etc. I would do as you suggest and use a list with a loop to initialize:

```
for i in some_range:
    karta[i]=karte()
```

Comment: It's better to use a list comprehension, but this solution is correct.